# get a JSON token in C#

Tags: c#, json

I get the following JSON file by accessing a REST API in C#

```json
[{
        "id": 71,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "Espace priv\u00e9",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-07-12T09:53:34+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-07-12T09:53:34+00:00",
        "owner": "Sylvain KRIER",
        "owner_id": "23"
    }, {
        "id": 80,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "CLI12",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-07-13T07:43:25+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-07-13T08:25:46+00:00",
        "owner": "Patrimoine Click",
        "owner_id": "2",
        "flags": 2
    }, {
        "id": 53,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "DOCUMENTATION",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-06-30T14:38:55+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-06-30T14:39:05+00:00",
        "owner": "Patrimoine Click",
        "owner_id": "2",
        "flags": 2
    }, {
        "id": 77,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "Mme AMSELLEM Smadar",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-07-12T10:33:29+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-07-12T10:33:42+00:00",
        "owner": "Patrimoine Click",
        "owner_id": "2",
        "flags": 2
    }, {
        "id": 68,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "Mr NGUIMFACK Guy",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-07-12T08:41:33+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-07-12T13:28:06+00:00",
        "owner": "Patrimoine Click",
        "owner_id": "2",
        "flags": 2
    }, {
        "id": 83,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "vergne-CLI1",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-07-13T08:20:06+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-07-13T08:23:29+00:00",
        "owner": "Sylvain KRIER",
        "owner_id": "23",
        "flags": 2
    }, {
        "id": 110,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "krier1",
        "can_read": true,
        "can_download": true,
        "can_write": true,
        "can_edit": true,
        "can_delete": true,
        "can_share": true,
        "creation": "2022-07-21T08:57:35+00:00",
        "modification": "2022-07-21T08:57:35+00:00",
        "owner": "Sylvain KRIER",
        "owner_id": "23",
        "flags": 2
    }
]
```

It's a folder list. I need to get the "id" of each folder with the "name"

I try to deserialize the JSON string like this, but it doesn't work :

```
var a = JObject.Parse(((RestSharp.RestResponseBase)resultat.Value).Content).SelectToken("id").ToList();
```

((RestSharp.RestResponseBase)resultat.Value).Content is the JSON string mentioned

Thanks for giving me help.

Comment: could you please be more specific about "it doesn't work"? **how exactly** does it not work?

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft? Then mind that [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) expects a JSON path and does not work like LINQ's `Select()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use linq to create a list

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

List<IdName> idNameList = JArray.Parse(json)
   .Select(j => new IdName { Id = (int)j["id"], Name = (string)j["name"] }).ToList();

public class IdName
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

result

```
[
  {
    "Id": 71,
    "Name": "Espace privé"
  },
  {
    "Id": 80,
    "Name": "CLI12"
  },
  {
    "Id": 53,
    "Name": "DOCUMENTATION"
  },
  {
    "Id": 77,
    "Name": "Mme AMSELLEM Smadar"
  },
  {
    "Id": 68,
    "Name": "Mr NGUIMFACK Guy"
  },
  {
    "Id": 83,
    "Name": "vergne-CLI1"
  },
  {
    "Id": 110,
    "Name": "krier1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I always deserialize my JSON to a statically typed object before doing anything else with it, in this case you can just create a mostly empty `JsonDirectory` class with just the `id` property and deserialize to a list of it, like so

```cs
public class JsonDirectory
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

// Deserialize
var json = "...";
var jsonDirectory = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonDirectory>>(json);

foreach (var jd in jsonDirectory)
    Console.WriteLine(jd.Id);
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XVg5I4)'s a demo showcasing his working on your example JSON

---

P.S this answer uses [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0), if you're using Newtonsoft.Json then you'll need to change out `[JsonPropertyName("id")]` with `[JsonProperty("id")]` and the deserialization line to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonDirectory>>(json)`